# How to fix empty record in SQLite3

Tags: php, sqlite, wamp, arabic

Current Environment:

- I'm using WampServer 2.5
- PHP 5.5.12

I'm getting empty row in sqlite3 all values in `TEXT`

As you see below:

```
$sql= 'CREATE TABLE ads (
       IDs TEXT,
       Countries TEXT,
       Types TEXT,
       SRs TEXT,
       Infos TEXT,
       Currency TEXT,
       Prices TEXT,
       Mobiles TEXT,
       Images TEXT 
)';
```

*Note: I'm inserting data in ARABIC*

Any help? Thank you.

Comment: Please show an insert command.

Comment: $statm ='INSERT INTO ADS(IDs, Countries, Types, SRs, Infos, Currency, Prices, Mobiles, Images) VALUES($id, $Contry, $type, $sr, $info, $Crouncy, $price, $mobile, $image)';
$db->exec($statm);

Comment: @user3465899 which column do you need to accept arabic values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure to change you're column collation to utf8:

```
ALTER TABLE `ads` CHANGE `IDs` `IDs` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
CHANGE `Countries` `Countries` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
CHANGE `Types` `Types` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
CHANGE `SRs` `SRs` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
CHANGE `Infos` `Infos` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
CHANGE `Currency` `Currency` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
CHANGE `Prices` `Prices` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
CHANGE `Mobiles` `Mobiles` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
CHANGE `Images` `Images` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

Comment: I did new db with this new (TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NULL DEFAULT NULL) setting for table
getting this Error :
SQLite3::exec(): near &quot;SET&quot;: syntax error

Comment: @user3465899 - here you go

Answer (score 0):

First, look at [pragma.html#pragma_encoding](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_encoding) for how to set up an'sqlite' database for different character sets. I would try the default first, which i believe is UTF-8.

I suggest that using PDO, in PHP, is the way to go. Also, i suggest always using prepared statements and 'marker variables' that way the 'driver' does all the work.

Here is a full working example of an insert:

```
<?php

$dsn = "sqlite:" . 'p:/temp/test.sqlite';
$options = array(
    \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
);
$db = new \PDO($dsn);
$db->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


$sql = 'INSERT INTO ADS (IDs, Countries, Types, SRs, Infos, Currency, Prices, Mobiles, Images) '
       .' VALUES( :id, :Contry, :type, :sr, :info, :Crouncy, :price, :mobile, :image)';

$statm = $db->prepare($sql);
$allOk = $statm->execute(array( ':id' => '1', ':Contry' => 'uk', ':type' => 'type1',
                           ':sr' => 'sr1', ':info' => 'info1', ':Crouncy' => 'crouncy1',
                           ':price' => 'price1', ':mobile' => 'mobile1', ':image' => 'image1',
         ));

var_dump($allOk);
```